# how can we achieve appearance of collection view as shown in image below?

Tags: ios, swift3

[image: I need such a kind of appearance in my app wherein a cell will be at the centre and part of cells on both sides.]
Also i need to have circular scrolling enabled for that collection view.
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: what the meaning of circular scrolling enabled

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  , circular scrolling means i.e., consider there are 5 cell in collection view , it should cycle like 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

[image]
First of all drag collection view in your respective ViewController and then select scroll direction as Horizontal in activity inspector.
[image]

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return collectionView.frame.size.width/2

    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.height) , (collectionView.frame.size.height))
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return img_Arr.count
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCaptureCell
        cell.CapturedImage.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
        let capt = UIImage(data:img_Arr[indexPath.row] as! NSData,scale:1.0)
        cell.CapturedImage.image = capt

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        //cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    // change background color back when user releases touch
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        //        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }
```

Additionaly give search bar on top and connet to the table delegate